# Binary Tree InOrderWalk implementation not working as expected

Tags: c, pointers, gdb, binary-tree, inorder

I am trying to implement a Binary Tree data structure in C and do an inorder traversal after a few inserts.
The program only prints the first element I have inserted and not any of the other nodes.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct tree
{

   struct node *root;

};


struct node
{

  int val;

  struct node *left;

  struct node *right;

};


struct tree *init ()
{

  struct tree *t = malloc (sizeof (struct tree));


  t->root = NULL;

  return t;

}



void insert (struct tree *t, int val)
{

  struct node *succ;

  struct node *new = malloc (sizeof (struct node));


  new->val = val;

  new->left = NULL;

  new->right = NULL;


  succ = NULL;

  struct node *insertPlace = t->root;

  while (insertPlace != NULL)
  {

       succ = insertPlace;

       if (insertPlace->val < new->val)

       insertPlace = insertPlace->right;

       else

       insertPlace = insertPlace->left;

   }

  if (succ == NULL)
    t->root = new;

  else if (new->val < succ->val)

    insertPlace = succ->right;

  else

   insertPlace = succ->left;

}



void inorderWalk (struct node *p)
{

  if (p != NULL)
  {

    if (p->left != NULL)
      inorderWalk (p->left);

    printf ("%d ", p->val);

    if (p->right != NULL)
       inorderWalk (p->right);

  }

}



void
print (struct tree *t)
{

struct node *p;

p = t->root;


inorderWalk (p);


} 



int

main ()
{

struct tree *t = init ();

insert (t, 5);

insert (t, 15);

insert (t, 20);

insert (t, 1);

insert (t, 2);

insert (t, 4);

insert (t, 10);


print (t);


return 0;

}
```

The code is also available [here](http://onlinegdb.com/BJwq_LiyZ) with an online gdb debugger.

Any feedback on why the code is not working as expected would be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't adding elements to the tree, apart from the root.  Setting `insertPlace = succRight` only updates the `insertPlace` variable, not anything in your tree.

I would recommend setting the value of the left or right node in the actual loop that is looking for the correct node:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct tree
{
   struct node *root;
};


struct node
{
  int val;

  struct node *left;

  struct node *right;
};


struct tree *init ()
{
  struct tree *t = malloc (sizeof (struct tree));
  t->root = NULL;
  return t;
}



void insert (struct tree *t, int val)
{

  struct node *succ;

  struct node *new = malloc (sizeof (struct node));
  new->val = val;
  new->left = NULL;
  new->right = NULL;

  succ = NULL;

  struct node* insertAtNode=t->root;
  if (insertAtNode==NULL) {
    t->root=new;
    return;
  }
  do {
    if (insertAtNode->val < new->val) {
      if (insertAtNode->right==NULL) {
        insertAtNode->right=new;
        return;
      } else {
        insertAtNode=insertAtNode->right;
      }
    } else if (insertAtNode->left==NULL) {
      insertAtNode->left=new;
      return;
    }
    else {
      insertAtNode=insertAtNode->left;
    }
  }
  while(1);
}



void inorderWalk (struct node *p)
{
  if (p != NULL)
  {
    if (p->left != NULL)
      inorderWalk (p->left);
    printf ("%d ", p->val);
    if (p->right != NULL)
       inorderWalk (p->right);
  }
}



void print (struct tree *t)
{
  struct node *p;

  p = t->root;

  inorderWalk (p);
  printf("\n");
}



int main ()
{
  struct tree *t = init ();

  insert (t, 5);

  insert (t, 15);

  insert (t, 20);

  insert (t, 1);

  insert (t, 2);

  insert (t, 4);

  insert (t, 10);


  print (t);


  return 0;

}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Now nodes are inserted properly and traversed in the correct order. Thanks a lot, Paul!